# How cast value as tuple (string, bool)

Tags: c#, casting, tuples

It is possible to cast as tuple in this way?

```
(string value, bool flag) value1 = MethodInfo.Invoke(this, param) as (string, bool);
```

Unfortunately it throw:

> "The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type
> ('(string, bool)' is a non-nullable value type)"

Only work in this way:

```
Tuple<string, bool> value1 = MethodInfo.Invoke(this, param) as Tuple<string, bool>;
```

Comment: `(string, bool)` denotes a `ValueTuple<string, bool>`, not a `Tuple<string, bool>`.

Comment: Clearly, (since it produces a compiler error) it isn't possible to "cast as tuple in this way".

Comment: Just cast it normally: `(string value, bool flag) = ((string, bool))MethodInfo.Invoke(this, param);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cast expression to cast:

```
(string value, bool flag) tuple = ((string, bool)) MethodInfo.Invoke(this, param);
```

But unlike using `as`, this will crash if the return value of `Invoke` is not a `(string, bool)`. If you don't like that, you can use pattern matching:

```
if (methodInfo.Invoke(this, param) is (string value, bool flag))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"({value}, {flag})");
    // assign it to a new variable if you want it as one "thing":
    (string value, bool flag) tuple = (value, flag);
}
```